# How to save multiple PlayerPrefs to cloud save

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-play-services

Im using google play services cloud save. I found a tutorial about how to save, but for one thing like just for highscore. I want to save multiple playerprefs, for example I have 3 ability and every one of it is saving in a playerpref so I want to save them in to the cloud and I have gold to buy these abilitys and you can buy the gold with IAP so I want to save gold too in cloud but I have no idea how to save multiple playerprefs can you help me.

My playerprefs is like this

PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Revive", revive);

PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SlowTime", slowTime);

PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Immortal", immortal);

Im changing and saving the gold after IAP purchase

PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Gold", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold") + 250);

This is the Cloud Save Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.SavedGame;
using System.Text;
using System;

public class PlayGamesController : MonoBehaviour

{
public static PlayGamesController Instance { set; get; }

const string Save_Name = "Save";
bool isSaving;
bool isCloudDataLoaded = false;

private void Start()
{
    if (Instance == null)
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        Instance = this;
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(Save_Name))
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(Save_Name, "0");

    if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("IsFirstTime"))
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("IsFirstTime", 1);

    LoadLocal();

    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().EnableSavedGames().Build();

    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);

    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

    SignIn();
}

private void SignIn()
{
    Social.localUser.Authenticate((success) => {
        LoadData();
    });
}

public void AddScoreToLeaderboard(string leaderboardId, long score)
{
    Social.ReportScore(score, leaderboardId, (bool success) => { });
}

public void OnAchievementClick()
{
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        Social.ShowAchievementsUI();
    }
    if (!Social.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        SignIn();
    }
}

public void OnLeaderboardClick()
{
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
    }
    if (!Social.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        SignIn();
    }
}

#region Saved Games

string GameDataToString()
{
    return CloudVariables.highScore.ToString();
}

void StringToGameData(string cloudData, string localData)
{
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("IsFirstTime") == 1)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("IsFirstTime", 0);
        if (int.Parse(cloudData) > int.Parse(localData))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(Save_Name, cloudData);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(int.Parse(localData) > int.Parse(cloudData))
        {
            CloudVariables.highScore = int.Parse(localData);
            AddScoreToLeaderboard(GPGSIds.leaderboard_high_score, CloudVariables.highScore);
            isCloudDataLoaded = true;
            SaveData();
            return;
        }
    }
    CloudVariables.highScore = int.Parse(cloudData);
    isCloudDataLoaded = true;
}

void StringToGameData(string localData)
{
    CloudVariables.highScore = int.Parse(localData);
}

public void LoadData()
{
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        isSaving = false;
        ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.OpenWithManualConflictResolution(Save_Name, DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork, true, ResolveConflict, OnSavedGameOpened);
    }
    else
    {
        LoadLocal();
    }
}

private void LoadLocal()
{
    StringToGameData(PlayerPrefs.GetString(Save_Name));
}

public void SaveData()
{
    if (!isCloudDataLoaded)
    {
        SaveLocal();
        return;
    }
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        isSaving = true;
        ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.OpenWithManualConflictResolution(Save_Name, DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork, true, ResolveConflict, OnSavedGameOpened);
    }
    else
    {
        SaveLocal();
    }
}

private void SaveLocal()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(Save_Name, GameDataToString());
}

private void ResolveConflict(IConflictResolver resolver, ISavedGameMetadata original, byte[] originalData, ISavedGameMetadata unmerged, byte[] unmergedData)
{
    if (originalData == null)
        resolver.ChooseMetadata(unmerged);
    else if (unmergedData == null)
        resolver.ChooseMetadata(original);
    else
    {
        string originalStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(originalData);
        string unmergedStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(unmergedData);

        int originalNum = int.Parse(originalStr);
        int unmergedNum = int.Parse(unmergedStr);

        if(originalNum > unmergedNum)
        {
            resolver.ChooseMetadata(original);
            return;
        }
        else if (unmergedNum > originalNum)
        {
            resolver.ChooseMetadata(unmerged);
            return;
        }
        resolver.ChooseMetadata(original);
    }
}

private void OnSavedGameOpened(SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game)
{
    if(status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success)
    {
        if (!isSaving)
            LoadGame(game);
        else
            SaveGame(game);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!isSaving)
            LoadLocal();
        else
            SaveLocal();
    }
}

private void LoadGame(ISavedGameMetadata game)
{
    ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.ReadBinaryData(game, OnSavedGameDataRead);
}

private void SaveGame(ISavedGameMetadata game)
{
    string stringToSave = GameDataToString();
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(Save_Name, stringToSave);

    byte[] dataToSave = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToSave);

    SavedGameMetadataUpdate update = new SavedGameMetadataUpdate.Builder().Build();

    ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.CommitUpdate(game, update, dataToSave, OnSavedGameDataWritten);
}

private void OnSavedGameDataRead(SavedGameRequestStatus status, byte[] savedData)
{
    if(status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success)
    {
        string cloudDataString;
        if (savedData.Length == 0)
            cloudDataString = "0";
        else
            cloudDataString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(savedData);

        string localDataString = PlayerPrefs.GetString(Save_Name);

        StringToGameData(cloudDataString, localDataString);
    }
}

private void OnSavedGameDataWritten(SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game)
{

}
#endregion /Saved Games
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't use player prefs for game state 2) By fixing (1) you fix your problem.

Comment: If I'm not gonna use playerprefs what I'm gonna use. I don't know anything else

Comment: Presumably you know how files on a file system work and what JSON is. If not, I suggest looking them up.